# Print name of object

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to print the name of the object defined in the print statement. here the name of the oblect is "rushi" but i am getting some error.

```py
class Fas:
    gender=''
    age=''
    clg=''
    city=''
    pass

rushi=Fas()
rushi.gender='male'
rushi.age=27
rushi.clg='TAPMI'
rushi.city='ahmendabad'
print(rushi.gender)
    
def fas_info(student):
    student.name
    return ("the name of the student is {}, his age is {} studying in {} and hails from {}".format(student,student.age,student.clg,student.city))
    print(fas_info(rushi))
```

output:

```
male
the name of the student is **<__main__.Fas object at 0x0000027BF5B39250>**, his age is 27 studying in TAPMI and hails from ahmendabad
```

Expected output:

```
the name of the student is **rushi**, his age is 27 studying in TAPMI and hails from ahmendabad
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `format` string is wrong. You're using `student` instead of `student.name`:

```
.format(student,student.age,student.clg,student.city)
```

The output you're getting is what happens when you print a whole object instead of a property of it.

If you replace `student` with `student.name`, it will output the name:

```
.format(student.name,student.age,student.clg,student.city)
```

Alternatively, if you define a `__str__` method for the student, and have it return `self.name`, then printing `student` will print their name.